# How to filter in ngTables

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, angularjs-http

I am using ng-table to generate my table.
but my data has two column, the first one is an object.

My function in controller :

```
$scope.allServers = function() {
    $http.get("/volazi/getServers").success(function(data) {
        $scope.serversDTO = data;
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
            dataset: data
        });
    });
}
```

So my data will be like:

```
[{
    server {
        name: "ser1",
        date: "..",
        group: {
            name: "G1",
            created: ".."
        }
    },
    status
}, ...]
```

how i can use filter in html

```
<tr ng-repeat="sr in $data">
    <td title="'Name'" filter="{server.name: 'text'}" sortable="'server.name'">
        {{ sr.server.name }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Its not working like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved th proble by adding `''`

i replace

```
filter="{server.name: 'text'}"
```

by

```
filter="{'server.name': 'text'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the filter to the loop:

```
<tr ng-repeat="sr in $data | filter: { server.name: 'text' }">
```

Comment: I want to filter on evry column,

Answer (score 0):

This will be really very helpful :[LINK](http://iamisti.github.io/mdDataTable/)